# About the maximum of $n$ uniform$([0, 1])$ r.v.'s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_{i}$ be i.i.d uniform$([0, 1])$ r.v.'s. Let $M_{n} = \text{max}(X_{1}, ..., X_{n})$.

How do we show that $\mathbb{P}[M_{n} = X_{n}, M_{n+1} = X_{n+1} \text{ only finitely often}] = 1$?

I know $\mathbb{P}[M_{n} = X_{n} \text{ i.o.}] = 1$, which can be proved by considering it's complement and show it has a probability zero, because for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $M_{n}$'s staying being $X_{m}$ has probability zero. But I have no idea about this one about consecutive $X_{n}, X_{n+1}$. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may tackle this problem by invoking the 1st Borel–Cantelli lemma. To this end, consider the event

$$ E_n =\{ \text{$M_n = X_n$ and $M_{n+1} = X_{n+1}$} \}. $$

Then the desired assertion, $\mathbf{P}(E_n \text{ i.o.}) = 0$, will hold true if  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{P}(E_n) < \infty$. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(E_n)
&= \mathbf{P}(M_{n-1} \leq X_n \leq X_{n+1}) \\
&= \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{P}(M_{n-1} \leq X_n \leq X_{n+1} \mid M_{n-1})] \\
&= \mathbf{E}\bigl[ \tfrac{1}{2}(1 - M_{n-1})^2 \bigr].
\end{align*}

This expectation can be computed explicitly by noting that $F_{M_{n-1}}(x) = x^{n-1}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, resulting in the value

$$ \mathbf{P}(E_n) = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}. $$

This indeed confirms that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{P}(E_n)$ is finite and hence the conclusion follows.